# How to prevent window from auto scroll after resize a textarea?

Tags: javascript, events, scroll, usability

I'm doing a form to edit articles stored in a database. The body of the text of the article is edited in a textarea tag. The all form doesn't fit in the window, so there is scroll bar created by the browser. But the textarea also got a limit, and when the text is too large, a second scroll bar is created by the browser.

In order to improve usability, I did a simple code that resizes the textarea as text is edited, so the text is always visible and there is no second scroll bar (yes, I don't like writing in stack overflow with two scroll bars either!).

```
// This line is between some tasks of textEditUpdate function:
elemTextArea.style.height = Math.max(elemTextArea.scrollHeight, 200)+'px';
// This automatizes the process:
elemTextArea.addEventListener("input", textEditUpdate, false);
```

The problem is when the textarea is resized, the window is scrolled automatically until the cursor to be at the bottom of the page. The user lost the point where he was working (the movement is abrupt) and also don't see the text below the cursor - it's very annoying!

I'm in doubt about the best approach of the problem, don't know if there is a way of prevent this event or I'll have to keep track of the scroll position and correct it all the time… what do you think?

EDIT: [A Playable Test](http://www.gustavopi.ppg.br/temp/teste.textarea.html) Please make the window small to improve the effect, and note that it doesn't happens all the time - suddenly it scrolls!

Comment: I think: create plnkr.

Comment: a playable example of your problem...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://plnkr.co/edit/

Comment: I tried in jsfiddle, won't work. But I'll make a webpage.

Comment: Can you please describe the steps to recreate your problem?  Also, you're mucking with the default behavior of things.  Trust me when I say that if auto-expanding text boxes was the best usability, the guys who write the spec would have demanded it.

Comment: I'm glad you ask (soon I'll have to deal with this dilemma again) but I don't know how to explain better - language limitations. But if you click on "A Playable Test" link I'm sure you'll understand the question. I'm trying not to muck with default behavior but to please my users. I'm thinking about a simple text editor for large text instead of html text area.